# Being completely normal implies perfectly normal?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

I know that being perfectly normal implies being completely normal. But is the converse true?

I've read somewhere that $\overline S_\omega$ is a counterexample but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline{S}_\omega$?

Comment: oh sorry!i didn't explain. it has many properties that it is written on page 66 of Munkres's topology .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is an outline to show that the [ordinal space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Ordinal_space) $\omega_1 + 1 = [ 0 , \omega_1 ]$ (this is denoted by $\overline{S}_\Omega$ in Munkres's *Topology*) of all countable ordinals together with the least uncountable ordinal under the order topology is completely normal but not perfectly normal.  An important thing about this space is that for each $\beta \in [0,\omega_1]$ the family of all sets of the form $$( \alpha , \beta ] = \{ \xi \in [0,\omega_1] : \alpha < \xi \leq \beta \}$$ for $\alpha < \beta$ is a neighbourhood base at $\beta$.

- It is completely normal because all linearly ordered spaces are completely normal.  Okay, that might be too short of an outline. For this particular space, suppose that $A, B \subseteq [0,\omega_1]$ are nonempty separated subsets (*i.e.*, $A \cap \overline{B} = \varnothing = \overline{A} \cap B$). Without too much loss of generality we may assume that $0$ does not belong to either set (it is an isolated point of the space).

  - For each $\alpha \in A$ find a $\gamma_\alpha < \alpha$ such that $( \gamma_\alpha , \alpha ] \cap B = \varnothing$, and then set $U = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} ( \gamma_\alpha , \alpha ]$.
  - Similarly, for each $\beta \in B$ find a $\delta_\beta < \beta$ such that $( \delta_\beta , \beta ] \cap A = \varnothing$.  Then set $V = \bigcup_{\beta \in B} ( \delta_\beta , \beta ]$.

  Show that these are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $A$, $B$, respectively.
- It is not perfectly normal because $\{ \omega_1 \}$ is a closed subset which is not G$_\delta$.  (To show that if $\{ U_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a family of open neighbourhoods of $\omega_1$, then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n \neq \{ \omega_1 \}$ note that if $\{ \alpha_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a countable family of countable ordinals, then $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \alpha_n$ is also a countable ordinal. For each $n$ pick $\alpha_n < \omega_1$ such that $( \alpha_n , \omega_1 ] \subseteq U_n$.)

Comment: why the singletons in this space are closed?

Comment: @user115608: Well, singletons in any [linearly ordered space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) are closed: $X \setminus \{ x \} = ( \leftarrow , x ) \cup ( x , \rightarrow )$ is open.

Comment: Linearly ordered spaces are Hausdorff, and singletons are closed in Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Being that definitions relating to separation tend not to agree, I thought it prudent to add the definitions used in $\pi$-Base. They are the ones found in Willard's *General Topology*, which seems to be fairly standard.

A **completely normal** space is one for which any subspace is normal (under the subspace topology). Equivalently, a space is completely normal provided any two separated sets can be placed into disjoint open sets.

A space $X$ is **perfectly normal** if, for distinct closed sets $A$ and $B$, there is a continuous function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(A) = \{0\}$ and $f^{-1}(B) = \{1\}$.

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/), an online version of Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*, lists the following spaces as completely normal but not perfectly normal. You can view the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Completely%20normal%2B%7EPerfectly%20normal) to learn more about these spaces.

Alexandroff Square

Baire Product Metric on Rω

Closed Ordinal Space [0,Ω]

Concentric Circles

Countable Excluded Point Topology

Deleted Integer Topology

Either-Or Topology

Finite Excluded Point Topology

Fortissimo Space

Hjalmar Ekdal Topology

Indiscrete Topology

Lexicographic Ordering on the Unit Square

Nested Interval Topology

Odd-Even Topology

One Point Compactification Topology

Open Ordinal Space [0,Ω)

Right Order Topology on R

Sierpinski Space

The Extended Long Line

The Integer Broom

The Long Line

Uncountable Excluded Point Topology

Uncountable Fort Space

Comment: thnx a lot!what an interesting one!